# duplicate attribute 'style' error in xml

Tags: android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have a button added on my xml file, the following is my code:

```
<Button
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    style="@style/button_style"
  />
```

Quite honestly I dont know coding, I'm only learning it. As you can see, I am using two styles and how do i merge them?

Comment: Why not copy pasting the style from on file to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be to change your `button_style` file to inherit from `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` file.
Inside your `button_style` file you need something like following

```
<style name="button_style" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
 .....
</style>
```

Then change your layout code as following

```
<Button
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    style="@style/button_style"
  />
```

Comment: Idk if your method worked because I don't see any difference from when having that @style/widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored and not having it. How do I know what that (widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored) is? Thank you anyway because Its not generating any errors now and it seems they merged even though it doesnt seem to be making a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
< Button
android:text="Login"
android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
android:layout_height="35dp"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

select a prefered Style. Probably that above or this below.

```
< Button
android:text="Login"
android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
android:layout_height="35dp"
style="@style/button_style" />
```